# Angular - Is there any Angular 5 package that integrated ADFS

Tags: angular, adfs

I started working on a project which will develop an application uses multiple ADFS to authenticate request coming to Web API.

Therefore, I need to somehow make angular client to get a token from ADFS and attach it to http request everytime it goes to Web API.

The question is that I wonder if there is any package already did that?

I did find a [tutorial](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/adfs/) here but it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) out

In app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
    imports: [..., HttpClientModule  ], // important! HttpClientModule replaces HttpModule
    providers: [
        Adal5Service,
        { provide: Adal5HTTPService, useFactory: Adal5HTTPService.factory, deps: [HttpClient, Adal5Service] } //  // important! HttpClient replaces Http
  ]
```

Example

```
import { Adal5HTTPService, Adal5Service } from 'adal-angular5';
...
export class HttpService {
    constructor(
        private adal5HttpService: Adal5HTTPService,
        private adal5Service: Adal5Service) { }

public get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        const options = this.prepareOptions();
        return this.adal5HttpService.get(url, options)
    }

private prepareOptions():any{
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.adal5Service.userInfo.token}`);
        return { headers };
}
```